# Windows UI Automation select item of combobox

Tags: c#, .net, combobox, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

I'm trying to select an item based on its value with the Windows UI Automation API.

I have a class `ComboBox` which inherits from `UIAutomation.Element`.

Further I have a method on this combobox element which should be able to be called with a `string` to select the matching combobox-item

I've tried the following:

```
public void SetSelectedItem(string itemName, ITimeout timeout = null)
{
    var comboboxItem = this.GetSelf(timeout).FindAll(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.ListItem));

    var expandCollapsePattern = (ExpandCollapsePattern)this.GetSelf(timeout).GetCurrentPattern(ExpandCollapsePattern.Pattern);
    expandCollapsePattern.Expand();
    var itemToSelect = ?????

    var selectItemPattern = (SelectionItemPattern)itemToSelect.GetCurrentPattern(SelectionItemPattern.Pattern);
    selectItemPattern.Select();
}
```

But I don't really know how to retrieve the correct item at the line `var itemToSelect = ?????`.

The variable `comboboxItem` is of type `AutomationElementCollection` but unfortunately, Linq doesn't seem to be able with this type...

Do you know how to retrieve the correct item?

Or am I doing something else wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The combobox items are **children** of the listbox that is a child of the combobox.  To retrieve the items starting with the combobox, specify `TreeScope.Descendants` as the scope in the `FindAll` method.  You can then iterate the items current to find the one that matches your text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer thanks to the hints of @TnTinMn, thank you! :-)

```
public void SetSelectedItem(string itemName, ITimeout timeout = null)
{
    this.GetSelf(timeout).Expand();

    var list = this.GetSelf(timeout).FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.List), timeout);
    var listItem = list.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, itemName), timeout);

    listItem.Select();
}
```

Comment: What is "ITimeout" and "GetSelf"? I cannot use your code sample